# How not to run pipelines on specific commit message

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-pipelines

I have pipeline that makes some changes and commits another change which triggers another pipeline and I dont want that automatic update to trigger pipeline.

I had an idea that I will specify commit message and that ignore it, but for some reason I cannot get it working.

Can you help me with that?

```
variables:
  COMMIT_MESSAGE: "MyCommitMessage"

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE != $COMMIT_MESSAGE
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the `never` keyword and use a regex like this :

```
variables:
  COMMIT_MESSAGE: "MyCommitMessage"

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^.*COMMIT_MESSAGE/
      when: never
    - when: always
```

The `if` will be evaluate to `true` and the pipeline will never run.

Comment: I had to add - when: always to rules and after that your solution worked.

Comment: Yes you're right, you want it to be triggered for all other cases. I have edited the answer to match your requirements.